# Script para cambiar el subrayado en color negro de un epub a color rojo no funciona cuando el fichero epub o la ruta contienen nombres con espacios

Tags: linux, script, zip, epub

El script funciona perfectamente, pero no completa la tarea cuando el fichero epub o la ruta en la que se encuentra contiene nombres con espacios.

```
# !/bin/bash

# Convierte el subrayado en negro de un epub a rojo  

echo "Nombre del fichero epub:"
read epub

# Descomprimir el epub en .tmpfolder  
unzip $PWD/$epub -d $PWD/.tmpfolder/

# Posicionarse en la carpeta  
cd $PWD/.tmpfolder

# Cambiar el color a rojo  
for file in OEBPS/Text/*.html; do awk '{gsub("<u>","<u style=\"text-decoration-color: red;\">"); print}' "$file" > "$file.tmp" && mv "$file.tmp" "$file"; done

# Volver a comprimir el epub  
zip -X $epub mimetype
zip -r $epub * -x mimetype

# Subir un nivel  
cd ..

# Borrar el epub antiguo  
rm $epub

# Copiar el nuevo epub un nivel arriba  
cp $PWD/.tmpfolder/$epub $PWD/

# Borrar la carpeta .tmpfolder  
rm -r .tmpfolder
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías encapsular entre "" todas las variables por las que pase el nombre del fichero de ese modo los espacios conformarán parte del argumento y no serán un separador de argumentos

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias, Manuel Barallobre Seoane, funciona perfectamente. Pego el nuevo código por si alguien lo necesita:

```
# !/bin/bash

# Convierte el subrayado en negro de un epub a rojo  

echo "Nombre del fichero epub:"
read epub

# Descomprimir el epub en .tmpfolder  
unzip "$PWD/""$epub" -d "$PWD/".tmpfolder/

# Posicionarse en la carpeta  
cd "$PWD/".tmpfolder

# Cambiar el color a rojo  
for file in OEBPS/Text/*.html; do awk '{gsub("<u>","<u style=\"text-decoration-color: red;\">"); print}' "$file" > "$file.tmp" && mv "$file.tmp" "$file"; done

# Volver a comprimir el epub  
zip -X "$epub" mimetype
zip -r "$epub" * -x mimetype

# Subir un nivel  
cd ..

# Borrar el epub antiguo  
rm "$epub"

# Copiar el nuevo epub un nivel arriba  
cp "$PWD/".tmpfolder/"$epub" "$PWD/"

# Borrar la carpeta .tmpfolder  
rm -r .tmpfolder
```

Comment: Si este código ya funcionó, podrías marcarla como la respuesta correcta, Luis Miguel.